# Passing variable from middleware to blade

Tags: laravel, variables, laravel-blade

This is what my middleware looks like

```
public function share(Request $request): array
    {
        return array_merge(parent::share($request), [

            'notifier' => fn() => session()->get('notifier'),

            'request_filters' =>  fn() => request()->filter,

            'media' => fn() => Media::query()
                ->when(request()->media_search, fn($q) => $q->search(request()->media_search))
                ->paginate(15),

            'user_roles' => Auth::id() ? Auth::user()->getRoleNames() : [],

            'actual_user' => fn() => session('actual_user') ?? null,

            'company_pages' => fn() => Auth::id() ? Page::forCompany(Auth::company())->forType('page')->get() : [],

            'primary' => 'test',


        ]);
    }
```

Now I want to take "Primary" and display it in the blade template. How do I do this?

Error is : Undefined variable $primary

I tried

```
{{$primary}}
```

Comment: what part of this is a middleware?

Answer (score 0):

You can add primary to the request object.
And retrieve it anywhere.

```
$request->primary = "test";
```